Go/Xml Namespaces
I'm defining an XML structure in Go using the encoding/xml package where the XML name contains the URL of the xsi and xsd namespaces.
Here's my struct:
struct:
type MensagemEnvioANS struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"http://url mensagemEnvioANS"`
    Xsd     string   `xml:"http://url xmlns:xsd,attr"` 
    Xsi     string   `xml:"http://url xmlns:xsi,attr"`  
}

main.go:
XML := schema.MensagemEnvioANS{
    Xsd: "http://url",          
    Xsi: "http://url", 
    Cabecalho: &schema.CabecalhoTransacao{
        RegistroANS:  "RegistroANS",
        VersaoPadrao: "VersaoPadrao",
        IdentificacaoTransacao: &schema.IdentificacaoTransacao{
            TipoTransacao:         "TipoTransacao",
            NumeroLote:            "NumeroLote",
            CompetenciaLote:       "CompetenciaLote",
            DataRegistroTransacao: "DataRegistroTransacao",
            HoraRegistroTransacao: time.Now(),
        },
    },
}

However, when I encode this struct to XML, the result for xsd and xsi returns like this:
<mensagemEnvioANS xmlns="http://url" xmlns:url="http://url" url:xmlns:xsd="" url:xmlns:xsi="">
